# Trouble sending emails with attachments with Rails 3.0.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Am using rails 3.0.7 & Mail (gem) 2.2.19.

When I try to send the email with attachments, Instead of showing up as a downloadable attachment, I rather get the attachment as plain-text in the email.

I have

```
attachments["example.png"] = File.read("path to image file")
```

I also tried

```
attachments["rails.png"] = {:content=>File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/images/rails.png"),
                            :mime_type=>"images/png"}
```

none of the above worked.

Can some one help me out of this mire.

Comment: your first shot is ok, how do you code the path?

Comment: Do you have this issue on localhost or elsewhere ?
May-be this came from a security limitation in one mail server delivering the mail...

Comment: Hi. i am a co-developer with satya. We tried Sendgrid and it still didn't work. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi. i am a co-developer with satya. The path given was "#{Rails.root}/public/images/rails.png"

Comment: Guys, I have deployed the code on Heroku. The problem still persists.

Comment: We're getting the same issue - it was working fine before and has recently broken. Could it be a problem with the gems?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and in my case the solution was to swap the attachment and mail lines. First attach, then call mail.

**WRONG**

```
def pdf_email(email, subject, pdfname, pdfpath)
  mail(:to => email, :subject => subject)
  attachments[pdfname] = File.read(pdfpath)
end
```

**GOOD**

```
def pdf_email(email, subject, pdfname, pdfpath)
  attachments[pdfname] = File.read(pdfpath)
  mail(:to => email, :subject => subject)
end
```